# In clojure, how does one bind from a map?

Tags: clojure

Given the map:

```
(def myMap {"a" 1 "b" 2 "c" 3 "d" 4 "e" 5 "f" 6})
```

I wish to use `let` to bind each key to each value. What is the most concise way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

with `myMap` as declared, destructuring of string keys seems like the best bet:

```
(let [{:strs [a b c d e f]} myMap] 
    (println a b c d e f))
;=> 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Cool. Didn't know about destructuring of string keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can use desctructuring:

I would suggest first to convert all keys to keywords using custom function like this:

```
(defn keywordize [map]
  (into {} 
    (for [[k v] map]
      [(keyword k) v])))
```

And then use destructuring:

```
(let [{:keys [a b c d e f]} (keywordize myMap)]
  (println a b c d e f))
```

Comment: Beat me to it, Nikita.

Comment: Thanks Nikita, conversion to keywords looks like a good step. However, with respect, I find the destructuring a little inelegant (not that I could do better :)). Suppose there were 100 keys in the map, I would need to write `[{:keys [a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 ... a98 a99 a100]} (keywordize myMap)]`.

Comment: You could create a vector using `(vec keys myMap)` of the keywords automatically and pass that to the :keys function.

Comment: That should be `(vec (keys myMap))`.

Comment: @ChrisDevo - :keys isn't a function in this case, so you can't just pass in ``(vec (keys myMap))``, you would need a macro to do what you propose.

Comment: @user2179977 A function that requires a hundred arguments, all playing different roles, is quite unlikely. Remember that you need only destructure the ones the function needs. If the  hundred arguments were homogeneous, you'd probably supply them as a vector.